# Check if String.Contain contain element from list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to do simple thing checking whether string contains elememnt from list or not.

```
 // if(Change.Any(x => x.Contains(pname)))
     if (pname.Contains(Change.Count.ToString())  )
        {
            print("ole");
             Health = System.Convert.ToInt32(changer);
             Health ++;
             changer = Health .ToString();
             pname = cName + changer;
        }
```

Comment: You're checking if the `pname` string contains a number inside it. The commented line was already correct! What issue are you facing?

Comment: if pname = MyVolume 1 and Change have element like {1,2,3,4} ,Checking whether pname contain any word from change or not

Comment: @paulp we need to see the data types for `pname` and `Change`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
Change.Any(x => pname.Contains(x));
```

which checks if any element [x] in `Change` list is contained inside the string `pname`

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using an extension on your strings if your code frequently does this kind of check (for a "cleaner" read), see the added code below - it tests an extension class for string that does the same thing; but your production code would read "MyString.HasAnyElementsOfList(MyListOfStrings)".

Just a thought, not a requirement - hope it helps! Happy coding!
-Darth

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Test]
    public void StringFromListIsFoundInString()
    {
        var listOfString = new List<string>() {"test", "bigword", "sillyword"};
        var stringToSearch = "this is a test";

        Assert.That(stringToSearch.HasAnyElementsOfList(listOfString), Is.EqualTo(true));
    }        
}

public static class MyStringExtensions
{
    public static bool HasAnyElementsOfList(this string stringToSearch, List<string> listOfStrings)
    {
        return listOfStrings.Any(listString => stringToSearch.Contains(listString));
    }
}
```